# Collection , Stream

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

в чем разница между коллекцией(Collection) и потоком(Stream)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллекция - это структура данных

Stream - инструмент для формирования структур данных

Answer (score 3):

Помимо вышеназванного отличием также является то, что коллекция грузит сразу все элементы в память, а при использовании `Stream`элементы загружаются и обрабатываются небольшими порциями.